# Wordpress Find Index of Post in Query

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I am trying to return the rank of a post within a custom query in wordpress. My code is currently

```
function post_rank($post_type,$meta_value,$post_id) {

$args = array (

    'post_type'              => $post_type,

    'meta_key'       => 'totalvotes',

    'order'                  => 'DESC',

    'orderby'                => 'meta_value_num',

    'post_status'              => '\'submitted\'

);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

$total_in_search = $the_query->found_posts;



$rank_in_search = array_search ($the_query,$post_id) +1 ;

$overall= $rank_in_search ."/".$total_in_search ;

wp_reset_postdata();

return $overall;

}
```

But i can't seem to find the post index. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query it must be

```
$current_post (available during The Loop) Index of the post currently being displayed.
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to do this outside of the loop?

Comment: what info about the post do you have?

Comment: The post_id. What i am trying to do is get the rank of a post within my quary ordered by the post meta totalvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually used a loop as follows:

```
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

            if ($post_id == get_the_ID()) 
            {
                $rank_in_search = $i;             }

$i++;

        endwhile;
```

Not the cleanest of approaches but will do for the time being. Any improvements always appreciated